# TensorFlow training is not working: model is not learning data

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, regression

I have a dataset with over 17 million observations, and I am trying to use that to train a `DNNRegressor` model. However, the training is not working at all. The loss is on the order of 10^15, which is just horrifying. I've been trying different things for several weeks and no matter what I do I cannot get the loss to go down.

For example, after training I make a test predition with one of the same observations used to train the data. The expected result is `140944.00`, but the prediction yeilds `-169532.5`, which is rediculous. There aren't even any negative values in the training data, I don't understand how it can be so off.

Here is some sample training data:

```py
Amount      Contribution    ServiceType     Percentile       Time   Result
214871.00   3501.00         SM23            high             50     17807828.00
214871.00   3501.00         SM23            high             51     19216520.00
214871.00   3501.00         SM23            high             52     19676064.00
214871.00   3501.00         SM23            high             53     21038840.00
214871.00   3501.00         SM23            high             54     22248295.00
214871.00   3501.00         SM23            high             55     22412713.00
28006.00    83.00           SM0             i_low            0      28006.00
28006.00    83.00           SM0             i_low            1      28804.00
28006.00    83.00           SM0             i_low            2      30140.00
28006.00    83.00           SM0             i_low            3      31598.00
28006.00    83.00           SM0             i_low            4      33130.00
28006.00    83.00           SM0             i_low            5      34663.00
```

This is my code:

```py
feature_columns = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Amount', dtype=dtypes.float32),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Contribution', dtype=dtypes.float32),
    tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
            'ServiceType',
            [
                'SM0',  'SM1',  'SM2',  'SM3',
                'SM4',  'SM5',  'SM6',  'SM7',
                'SM8',  'SM9',  'SM10', 'SM11',
                'SM12', 'SM13', 'SM14', 'SM15',
                'SM16', 'SM17', 'SM18', 'SM19',
                'SM20', 'SM21', 'SM22', 'SM23'
            ],
            dtype=dtypes.string
        ),
        dimension=16
    ),
    tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
        tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
            'Percentile',
            ['i_low', 'low', 'mid', 'high'],
            dtype=dtypes.string
        ),
        dimension=16
    ),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('Time', dtype=dtypes.int8)
]

model = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
    hidden_units=[64, 32],
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    model_dir=os.getcwd() + "\job",
    label_dimension=1,
    weight_column=None,
    optimizer='Adagrad',
    activation_fn=tf.nn.elu,
    dropout=None,
    input_layer_partitioner=None,
    config=RunConfig(
        master=None,
        num_cores=4,
        log_device_placement=False,
        gpu_memory_fraction=1,
        tf_random_seed=None,
        save_summary_steps=100,
        save_checkpoints_secs=0,
        save_checkpoints_steps=None,
        keep_checkpoint_max=5,
        keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours=10000,
        log_step_count_steps=100,
        evaluation_master='',
        model_dir=os.getcwd() + "\job",
        session_config=None
    )
)

print('Training...')
model.train(input_fn=get_input_fn('train'), steps=100000)

print('Evaluating...')
model.evaluate(input_fn=get_input_fn('test'), steps=4000)

print('Predicting...')
prediction = model.predict(input_fn=get_input_fn('predict'))

print(list(prediction))
```

The `input_fn` is computed as follows:

```py
def split_input():
    data = pd.read_csv('C:\\all_data.txt', sep='\t')

    x = data.drop('Result', axis=1)
    y = data.Result

    return train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=123)


def get_input_fn(input_fn_type):
    train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = split_input()

    if input_fn_type == 'train':
        return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
            x=train_x,
            y=train_y,
            num_epochs=None,
            shuffle=True
        )
    elif input_fn_type == 'test':
        return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
            x=test_x,
            y=test_y,
            num_epochs=1,
            shuffle=False
        )
    elif input_fn_type == 'predict':
        return tf.estimator.inputs.pandas_input_fn(
            x=pd.DataFrame(
                {
                    'Amount': 52050.00,
                    'Contribution': 1394.00,
                    'ServiceType': 'SM0',
                    'Percentile': 'i_low',
                    'Time': 5
                },
                index=[0]
            ),
            num_epochs=1,
            shuffle=False
        )
```

The output is as follows:

```py
Training...
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 6.30944e+15, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 457.091
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3.28245e+15, step = 101 (0.219 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 533.271
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 2.65647e+15, step = 201 (0.188 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 533.274
...
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.06601e+15, step = 99701 (0.203 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 533.289
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 2.12652e+15, step = 99801 (0.188 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 533.273
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.31647e+15, step = 99901 (0.203 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 100000 into C:\projection_model\job\model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 2.88956e+15.
Evaluating...
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [1/4000]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [2/4000]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [3/4000]
...
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [3998/4000]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [3999/4000]
INFO:tensorflow:Evaluation [4000/4000]
INFO:tensorflow:Finished evaluation at 2017-08-30-19:04:03
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 100000: average_loss = 1.37941e+13, global_step = 100000, loss = 1.76565e+15
Predicting...
[{'predictions': array([-169532.5], dtype=float32)}] # Should be somewhere around 140944.00
```

Why isn't the model learning the data? I've tried different regressors and input normalization, nothing is working.

Comment: A suggestion that should be relatively quick to try: as a test, and this is only a test, try using every ten thousandth data point so that the data set size is smaller and the troubleshooting correspondingly faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNRegressor) hides too many details, which is great if everything's working right away, but pretty frustrating when it needs some debugging.

For example, it's fairly possible that the learning rate is too large. You won't see the learning rate in your code, because it's chosen by `DNNRegressor`. By default, [it's 0.05](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dnn.py#L44), which is reasonable for many applications, but may be too large in your particular case. I suggest you instantiate the optimizer yourself `AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate)` and pass it to `DNNRegressor`.

It may be also possible that initial weights are too big. `DNNRegressor` uses [`tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/fully_connected) layers without overriding the 
`weights_initializer` and `biases_initializer`. Just as before, the default values are pretty reasonable, but if you want it to be different, you simply have no control over it.

What I usually do to check if the neural network is at least somehow working is reduce the training set to few examples and try to overfit the neural network. This experiment is very fast, so I can try various learning rates and other hyperparameters to find a sweet spot, and then move on to a bigger dataset.

Further troubleshooting: visualize the distributions of activations in each layer, the distribution of gradients or weights in [tensorboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard) to narrow down the problem.

Comment: I've already tried many different values for the learning rate with no success. However, I will look into the weight values and will also try to use only a few training examples.